# Parsing multiple C source files

Tags: c, parsing, antlr

I have multiple C source files and respective header files. I am trying to parse these files using a compiler, e.g. ANTLR.
In ANTLR parser grammar, you can define your header files using the

```
@parser::includes
{#include"a.h"}
```

You can start parsing the first file e.g.

```
CommonTree tree = Parser.start("a.c");
```

and parser will parse the header file

```
a.h
```

but how to parse the files if you have multiple source file e.g. b.c, c.c and so on with their respective header files.

Comment: You are gravely mistaken. The stuff you put inside the `@parser::includes` section will only cause these statements to appear inside the source file of your generated parser. In no way are these header files parsed by your parser.

Comment: B.t.w., aren't you the same user as: http://stackoverflow.com/users/628127/user628127 ?

Comment: Still it didn't answer my question.

Comment: I suggest you first learn ANTLR before proceeding any further. At least the basics of it. Now it's as if you were stepping into the cockpit of some machine you have never operated before, and start to press buttons and pull levers: nothing good can come from it.

Answer (score 3):

C is a pig to parse --- the semantic type of a token depends on what it's been declared as. Consider:

```
T(*b)[4]
```

If T is a type name, then this is a variable declaration. If it's an identifier, it's a functional call. In order to resolve this, any C parser that expects to actually work is going to have to keep a full type environment, which means it needs to be an unpleasantly large chunk of a C compiler.

There are ANTLR parsers for C that get all this stuff right but they're not trivial to use and I don't have any experience of them, so can't comment there.

Instead you might want to go look at using external tools to parse your C into something that's easier to deal with. [gcc-xml](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) is one such; it uses gcc itself to parse source files and then spit out XML that's much easier to handle.